# How can I certify that the data in a specified AWS region is actually in that region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a business requirement to confirm that the data stored in a specific AWS Region (ca-central-1) is actually stored in Canada. Is there any way to confirm this either through AWS, or in another way? Ideally, we would like point to a web page to show clients that their data is in fact in the country (Canada). Less ideally, we could show screenshots of the AWS console showing the client's EC2 and S3 in the ca-central-1 region but we are looking for something more "official".

Comment: Can you use the `aws` CLI?  You can run `aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket yourbucketname` but, of course, you'll need to have some credentials to run that.  I'm not sure if read-only S3 credentials would be better or worse than a screenshot.  You could create a website to do the same but that may not be "official".

Comment: *"We have a business requirement to confirm"* ...define "confirm."  I assume, from the question, that public assertions made by AWS such as [*"Objects belonging to a bucket that you create in a specific AWS Region never leave that region, unless you explicitly transfer them to another region. For example, objects stored in the EU (Ireland) region never leave it"*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) don't satisfy what you are looking for, but it is not clear what, exactly, you want to "confirm" or what such confirmation would look like.

Comment: We have clients that are not familiar with "the cloud" and its architecture. These clients are also apart of government departments that have to comply with a strict "in-country" data storage policy. When I say, "your data is in Canada", and they reply, "Prove it", I don't know how to do that. As developers, we just take AWS at its word and life goes on, not so simple for the layman. Ultimately, if there is really no way to "prove it" that is fine, we just had perform the due diligence to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dnslookup command. The following will give you the ip

```
dig +nocmd your.cloud any +multiline +noall +answer
```

Then you can use the following command to get the region:

```
curl freegeoip.net/xml/xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

this will get you the geolocation of the address. You can also use their [website](https://geoiptool.com/) if that helps

tested with: `curl freegeoip.net/xml/54.231.184.255`

response:

`<Response>
    <DeprecationMessage>This API endpoint is deprecated and will stop working on July 1st, 2018. For more information please visit: https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip#readme</DeprecationMessage>
    <IP>54.231.184.255</IP>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
    <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
    <RegionCode>OR</RegionCode>
    <RegionName>Oregon</RegionName>
    <City>Boardman</City>
    <ZipCode>97818</ZipCode>
    <TimeZone>America/Los_Angeles</TimeZone>
    <Latitude>45.7788</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-119.529</Longitude>
    <MetroCode>810</MetroCode>
</Response>`

Comment: Geolocation by IP address is an art, not a science.

Answer (score 0):

freegeoip will stop working in a couple of months.

Here is an alternative: https://geocoder.ca/54.231.184.255?geoit=xml

```
    <geodata>
    <latt>47.584095 </latt>
    <longt>-122.299566      </longt>
    <city>Mercer Island     </city>
    <prov>WA        </prov>
    <postal>98040   </postal>
    <stnumber>2121  </stnumber>
    <staddress>26TH AVE S   </staddress>
    <inlatt>47.5839 </inlatt>
    <inlongt>-122.2995      </inlongt>
    <distance>0.022 </distance>
    <NearRoad>25TH AVE S    </NearRoad>
    <NearRoadDistance>0.010 </NearRoadDistance>
    <neighborhood>Atlantic  </neighborhood>
    <TimeZone>America/Los_Angeles   </TimeZone>
    <AreaCode>206   </AreaCode>
    <confidence>0.9 </confidence>
    <intersection>
    <street1>26th Ave S     </street1>
    <street2>Walker St S    </street2>
    <lattx>47.583643        </lattx>
    <longtx>-122.299038     </longtx>
    <city>Mount Baker       </city>
    <prov>WA        </prov>
    <distance>0.045 </distance>
    </intersection>
    <major_intersection>
    <street1>Walker St S    </street1>
    <street2>25th Ave       </street2>
    <lattx>47.5835200000    </lattx>
    <longtx>-122.3001360000 </longtx>
    <city>Seattle   </city>
    <prov>WA        </prov>
    <distance>0.064 </distance>
    </major_intersection>
    <usa>
    <latt>47.5840948        </latt>
    <longt>-122.2995659     </longt>
    <uscity>Mercer Island   </uscity>
    <state>WA       </state>
    <zip>98040      </zip>
    <usstnumber>2121        </usstnumber>
    <usstaddress>26TH AVE S </usstaddress>
    <inlatt>47.5839 </inlatt>
    <inlongt>-122.2995      </inlongt>
    <distance>0.022 </distance>
    <NearRoad>25TH AVE S    </NearRoad>
    <NearRoadDistance>0.010 </NearRoadDistance>
    <neighborhood>Atlantic  </neighborhood>
    <TimeZone>America/Los_Angeles   </TimeZone>
    <AreaCode>206   </AreaCode>
    <confidence>0.9 </confidence>
    <intersection>
    <street1>26th Ave S     </street1>
    <street2>Walker St S    </street2>
    <lattx>47.583643        </lattx>
    <longtx>-122.299038     </longtx>
    <city>Mount Baker       </city>
    <prov>WA        </prov>
    <distance>0.045 </distance>
    </intersection>
    <major_intersection>
    <street1>Walker St S    </street1>
    <street2>25th Ave       </street2>
    <lattx>47.5835200000    </lattx>
    <longtx>-122.3001360000 </longtx>
    <city>Seattle   </city>
    <prov>WA        </prov>
    <distance>0.064 </distance>
    </major_intersection>
    <usa>
    <latt>47.5840948        </latt>
    <longt>-122.2995659     </longt>
    <uscity>Mercer Island   </uscity>
    <state>WA       </state>
    <zip>98040      </zip>
    <usstnumber>2121        </usstnumber>
    <usstaddress>26TH AVE S </usstaddress>
    <inlatt>47.5839 </inlatt>
    <inlongt>-122.2995      </inlongt>
    <distance>0.022 </distance>
    </usa>
    </geodata>
```